# Updatable view (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say we have the following:

```
create view view_1 as
(
  select key, data from some_table_or_view;
);

create table table_1
(
  key
  more_data
);

create view view_2 as
(
  select v1.key, v1.data, t1.more_data 
  from view_1 v1, table_1 t1 
  where v1.key = t1.key
);

create table table_2 as
(
  key
  data
  more_data
);

create view view_3 as
(
  select key, data, more_data from view_2
  union
  select key, data, more_data from table_2
);
```

So basically, we have joined two data feeds, one that comes from a join, one that is raw data.

I want to be able to do the following.

```
update view_3 set more_data = 'BLAH_MORE_DATA' where key = 'BLAH_KEY';
```

Where this somehow updates either `table_1` or `table_2` depending whether "BLAH_KEY" comes from `table_1` or `table_2`.

Currently the only way I can think of is:

```
create view view_3 as
(
  select 'TAB1' as source, key, data, more_data from view_2
  union
  select 'TAB2' as source, key, data, more_data from table_2
);
```

and then doing updates using a PL/SQL function which checks the source column and updates the appropriate table, but this means I have to kept the view and the PL/SQL function in sync.

I'm looking for a nicer way to do this.

Comment: Using PL/SQL procedures is already a nice way to implement complex logic :) I upvoted schurik's trigger answer because it works but I still would prefer the procedural approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an instead of trigger on the view_3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER view3_trg
INSTEAD OF  UPDATE
ON view_3
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :OLD.source = 'TAB1' THEN

  UPDATE table_1 t1
  set t1.data = :NEW.data
  WHERE
    t1.key = :OLD.key
  ;
ELSIF OLD.source = 'TAB2' THEN
   UPDATE table_2 t2
  set t2.data = :NEW.data
  WHERE
    t2.key = :OLD.key
  ;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapting schurik's answer and taking into account your comment about "else-if-heimer's disease":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER view3_trg
INSTEAD OF  UPDATE
ON view_3
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_1 t1
  set t1.data = :NEW.data
  WHERE t1.key = :OLD.key;

  UPDATE table_2 t2
  set t2.data = :NEW.data
  WHERE t2.key = :OLD.key;
END;
```

/

Answer (score 2):

```
create view view_2 as
(
  select v1.key, v1.data, t1.more_data 
  from view_1 v1, table_1 t1 
  where v1.key = t1.key
);
```

View_2 probably won't be updatable. Or at least only the columns of the child table in an enforced foreign key relationship.

Check user_updatable_columns to see which columns of a view can be automatically updated (ie where Oracle can work out that an update of the column can never be ambiguous). Using EMP and DEPT, for example, if SMITH and JONES work for the same department, you can't update the department name for SMITH alone (because the dept_name is an attribute of the parent), but you could update SMITH's salary.